# "Read beyond end of file" error when migrating Delphi 7 app To RAD Studio 10

Tags: delphi, structure, record, rad

I have an old program in Delphi 7 and want to convert it to RAD Studio 10.3.

The old program uses these record structures in a file.

```
TYPE
TPanel = RECORD
  Name     : String[40];
  Width    : Integer;
  Height   : Integer;
  TypeID   : String[20];
  TypeName : String[40];
  Price    : Extended;
END;

TWorktop = RECORD
  Width    : Integer;
  Height   : Integer;
  TypeID   : String[20];
  TypeName : String[40];
  Price    : Extended;
End;

TData = RECORD
  ID: String[20];
  IDName   : String[30];
  OrderName: String[30];
  OrderAdr : String[30];
  Quantity : Integer;
  CselcsicsAzon : String[30];
  dateCreate    : TDate;
  ProjectChanged: Boolean;
  PanelCount    : Integer;
  Panels   : Array[1..orderMaxPanel+1] Of TPanel;
  PanelCount    : Integer;
  Worktops : Array[1..orderMaxWorktop+1] Of TWorktop;
  WorktopCount  : Integer;
  Price    : Extended;
END;

Var
  Data: TData;
  F: File Of TData;

Begin
  AssignFile(F,Filename);
  Reset(F);
  Read(F,D);
  CloseFile(F);
End;
```

Delphi 7 reads the file OK.

RAD Studio 10.3 errors when reading the file (Read beyond end of file).

As I looked into it, the `String` type in RAD Studio is not the same as the Delphi 7 `String` type. It should be `AnsiString` instead.
But `AnsiString[40]` is not accepted.

How should I modify the code so that I can create the file in Delphi 7 and then read/write it in RAD Studio?

---

**UPDATE**:

The difference:

```
TTest = RECORD
    rhLeft,
    rhTop,
    rhRight,
    rhBottom    : Extended;
end;
```

Size is not equal in Delphi 7 and RAD Studio.

But:

```
TTest = RECORD
    rhLeft: Extended;
    rhTop: Extended;
    rhRight: Extended;
    rhBottom    : Extended;
end;
```

Size is equal, but Delphi 7 cannot read the file!

---

**UPDATE**:

The solution is **packed record**! Thanks!

Comment: Do you compile a 32-bit or a 64-bit executable? You can always check what `SizeOf( datatype )` evaluates to in each Delphi version/project settings - for `Extended` it should be 10 bytes for a 32-bit architecture and 8 bytes for 64-bit. And then in sum check `SizeOf( TPanel )` in both environments - it surely differs.

Comment: In Delphi 7 string usually is a class-based string ("huge string") and string[30] is always a short string of length 30. I'm not quite sure but you could try shortstring[30] instead

Comment: The application is 32-bit

Comment: ShortString[30]; -> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(44): E2029 ';' expected but '[' found

Comment: The [record's alignment](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=$align) is undefined (since you didn't use `packed record`). For D7 the default is `8`, for D10.3 it could be different. Again, check `SizeOf()` on each of your types. And please edit existing comments instead of adding multiple in a row - this is not a chat.

Comment: Your string declaration is fine. String[30] will be the same size as in Delphi 7, because those strings (declared with numbers) haven't changed. You should use packed record to keep consistent  record alignment with Delphi 7.

Comment: The string[n] fields you have in the code are *short string* types. Todays RAD Studio still supports this type. You should not change the code concerning these short string types. Note! Do not write *shortstring[30]* keep it as *string[30]*

Comment: @KissGe your 2nd `Update` should be posted as an answer instead of an edit. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @KissGe, please note that `Extended` size is platform dependent. See [System.Extended](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Extended)